# Using an OrderedDict in Jython

Tags: python, iteration, jython, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to use an OrderedDict in Jython.  When I write it in Python, it works fine; however, when I try the same code with Jython, it gives a Java error (I have also had it say that the collections module has no attribute OrderedDict).  The module error was as follows:

```
ERROR: Exception (main): 'module' object has no attribute 'OrderedDict'
```

So what I'm trying to do is output the values of the dictionary in the same order that they were put in.  I want to create the following functionality (written in Python) in Jython:

```
import collections

example = collections.OrderedDict()

example["c"] = 3
example["b"] = 4
example["d"] = 3
example["e"] = 9
example["a"] = 7

for key, value in example.iteritems():
    print key + ": " + str(value)
```

This would result in:

```
c: 3
b: 4
d: 3
e: 9
a: 7
```

Now I am ASSUMING that the reason this is not working for me in Jython is because OrderedDict does not exist in it.  With that being said, is there a way to do this in Jython?  Maybe it requires Java code?

EDIT:

I figured out a way to do it using a list and tuples, like so:

```
example = []

example.append(("c", 3))
example.append(("b", 4))
example.append(("d", 3))
example.append(("e", 9))
example.append(("a", 7))

for tup in example:
    key, value = tup
    print key + ": " + str(value)
```

While this works, I'd still like to know how to do it with a dictionary.

Comment: Your question should include the error that you saw.  I am guessing you saw something like this: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OrderedDict'`

Comment: correct, sorry - added it

Answer (score 3):

If you need `collections.OrderedDict`, you must use Jython version 2.7 or later, because `collections.OrderedDict` was not introduced into Python [until version 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: hmm.  Well, I'm using Sikuli (uses Jython), and apparently it's rocking jython-2.1..........